# MYSQL query: select between date with local format

Tags: mysql, date

my mysql database tb_date (varchar 20):

- 16 November 2014
- 06 December 2014
- 01 April 2014
- 12 April 2015

I want select between 01 January 2014 until 31 December 2014, how the query is with date conversion?

thanks..

Comment: Your date should be stored as date format or timestamp, not as varchar(20)...

Comment: MySQL has implemented specific datatypes for storing "date" values. If you only need to store a date, with no time component, you could use `DATE` datatype. If you are storing date and time together, then you could use either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. If you need to extract the date values in a specific format, you can use the `DATE_FORMAT` function in your query, or, you could do the formatting in the application or presentation layer, rather than the database query. Storing "date" values in a VARCHAR is wrong, for several reasons. And that includes negative impact to query performance.

Comment: I known, but there is a something and I must stored date as varchar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern, storing date values in VARCHAR columns, rather than using datatypes specifically designed and implemented for storing date values... `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

To answer your question, before it gets closed, you could use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert the strings into `DATE` datatype, and then do the comparison.  MySQL won't be able to make use of an index range scan operation, it will need to evaluate that function on every flipping row in the table.

As an example:

```
 SELECT t.mycol
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.mycol,'%d %M %Y') >= '2014-01-01'
    AND STR_TO_DATE(t.mycol,'%d %M %Y') <  '2015-01-01'
```

We'll need to check the MySQL Reference Manual to verify that `'%M'` is the right format specifier for the full month name...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Yes, it looks like I guessed right. `M` is the month name.

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented, you should store your date as Timestamp or Data format then you could simply compare.

However, there is still a solution.. You can convert the varchar to a date directly in your query :

```
select * from yourTable
  where (str_to_date(tb_date, '%d %M %Y') between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31');
```

But please don't use this hack and change your date format...

**Edit** : If you are really willing to use varchar to store your date, change it to varchar(17) which is the max character possible using your string format.